# Calculated field Date formula

Tags: 2010, list, calculated-column

I have a date field, and it has the date in the format - 11/2/2011 11:40 AM

**How ever my requirement is to get the date in the format - *02 Nov 2011 11:40 AM***

For that I created a calculated field for the said field and used the formula as - **=TEXT(Modified,"dd mmm yyyy hh:mm ")**

It resulted in the following date format - 02 Nov 2011 11:40 (It is a 24 hour format).

Now my question is how can I edit the formula to get the time in 12 hour format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the date/time format you are looking for is:

```
"dd mmm yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
```

This may be useful: [TEXT function reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx)