# Difference between two dates and hours

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list with three columns: Date 1, Date 2 (Both as date and time) and Difference (as a calculated column). I want get the difference between Date 1 and Date 2, but in hours and minutes. I found in TechNet this formula:

`=IF(ROUND(((Data 2 - Data 1)*24-ROUNDDOWN((Data 2 - Data 1)*24,0))*60,0)=60,(ROUNDDOWN(((Data 2 - Data 1)*24),0)&": 00"),(ROUNDDOWN(((Data 2 - Data 1)*24),0)&":"&ROUND(((Data 2 - Data 1)*24-ROUNDDOWN((Data 2 - Data 1)*24,0))*60,0)))`

But, if I have this scenario:

Date 1 as 31/07/2014 9:00 and Date 2 31/07/2014 9:05 the formula returns to me this result: 0:5

Is there any way to it returns 00:05?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There was already a similar question, see here: [Calculated field Date formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22529/calculated-field-date-formula).

Wrap up your calculated field with the [TEXT reference function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) Stuart has also   linked in his post.

So in your case, it would look something like this:

```
=TEXT(IF(ROUND(((Data 2 - Data 1)*24-ROUNDDOWN((Data 2 - Data 1)*24,0))*60,0)=60,
(ROUNDDOWN(((Data 2 - Data 1)*24),0)&": 00"),(ROUNDDOWN(((Data 2 - Data 
1)*24),0)&":"&ROUND(((Data 2 - Data 1)*24-ROUNDDOWN((Data 2 - Data 1)*24,0))*60,0))),
"hh:mm")
```