# How to customize DateTime format with AM or PM with Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

1. I would like to display a datetime format with AM or PM. I have
   tried with `hh:mm:ss tt` or `hh:mm tt` or `hh:mm zz` but it didn't
   work, it just display the time as `09:00 tt` or `09:30 zz`. Please
   give me some advice to address my problem.

It must be like this `01:30 PM` or `09:00:30 AM`

2. Besides with that current format, I am not sure that it is correct
   or not. I tried to update some documents at 09:00 AM but it displayed
   at 01:00...

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding "... AM/PM") to the end of your formula:

**=TEXT([Modified],"h:mm AM/PM")**

See Stuart's answer here: 
[Calculated field Date formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22529/calculated-field-date-formula])

Answer (score 1):

For displaying required time format use "t" instead of "tt"
Refer here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx